# React router 5: Redirect drops param value in browser's url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route defined as following:

```
<Route path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={SheetRoutes} />
```

And `SheetRoutes`:

```
const SheetRoutes = ({ match }: RouteComponentProps): JSX.Element => (
  <Switch>
    <Sheet>
      <Route
        exact
        path={`${match.path}/`}
        render={() => <Redirect to={`${match.path}/general`} />}
      />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/general`} component={GeneralRoutes} />
      ...
    </Sheet>
    <Redirect strict to='/404' push />
  </Switch>
);
```

I want when the user types `/5` in the url to redirect him to `/5/general`, in this case it works fine and the view is updated accordingly.

The problem I'm having is that the url in the browser drops the `id` value and it looks like this:  `/:id/general` instead of `/5/general`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Redirect` component in your `SheetRoutes`, it should be `match.url` (which is the real path value) instead of `match.path`.